# how to find out the RAM and GPU information of my visitors?

Tags: javascript, browser, gpu, ram

I want to know how much RAM my visitors have and all the information available about their GPU. Is there any way to achieve this via JavaScript or maybe ActionScript (Flash)?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464896/javascript-get-cpu-gpu-memory-information

Comment: Highly unlikely JavaScript can do this, and it's a little shady to use otherwise pointless Flash (which *might* be able to do this but I'm not really sure) to determine private system configuration data.

Comment: Why not just have users download and run a survey app if they want to give you this data, the way Steam does it? Or upload a dump from an existing tool for this like CPU-Z.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript, Browser extensions and Plugins are heavily sandboxed that they have limited, to no access to the system for security purposes. Only limited hardware can be accessed directly (with the user's consent), like camera and microphone for JavaScript's `getUserMedia` or Flash.

The nearest you can get is to have the user install something on the PC that interacts with the browser, like a Java applet. [Can You Run It](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri) uses this method to check the user's PC if it matches game requirements.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
navigator.deviceMemory
```

To find the device RAM in gigabytes.

See [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/deviceMemory#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Just here to point out. `navigator.deviceMemory` only returns the approximate amount of system memory, it is used to identify classes of devices (low-end, mid tier, and good tier)