# c# How do I get total RAM size on client machine

Tags: c#, memory, size, client, ram

How do I get total amount of RAM on the client machine? I know how to get RAM size from the server side as my code is hosted on the server but how do I retrieve client system information.

Comment: Yes, its a web application

Comment: Why would you need that?

Answer (score 0):

Client-side logic needs to be executed using JavaScript (or a browser extension), which is sandboxed, and doesn't provide access to that kind of information. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025490/1149773), it can't be done transparently. However, if this information is important for your application, you could use some technique that involves explicit user action, such as asking them to run an executable that communicates with your server.

Comment: Prompt: "Would you like to allow some random program access to your System specifics?"  Answer: No.

Comment: It's an intranet app.

Comment: @someone: If it's an intranet app, and your organization uses Active Directory, then there are other ways of getting the required information. For example, the executable could be deployed onto all machines automatically by an administrator, without user intervention. There might even be built-in facilities from Active Directory itself.