# Grid computing on the web

Tags: javascript, web-worker, grid-computing

I had idea to compute big data by client browser when they're visiting web sites with `web worker`.

as you know `web worker` run safe thread in back end of browser which doesn't affect on main web site, so web site can use client processors to compute somethings like cracking or ext.

I'm trying to implement it as free and open source service with web sites get code (something like google analytics or ...) so when user click on **use my processor during my visit of this site** web workers starts ,get data from server,compute and send result to server.

Now I have two questions about this:

first: What do you think about this idea? Is it can be useful?

sencod: How can I determine cpu usage in web worker?is it possible?(maybe some one has core i7 so more web worker on his browser can be run)

Comment: 1. is OT for this site, but in any case its been done before - cant remember the name of the firm, but they are no longer around, so it couldn't have been very successful. We do something similar, but decided use a full VM because its more secure, and gives better functionality 2. is OK for this site, but looks like dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464896/javascript-get-cpu-gpu-memory-information