# Get a visitor's System Hardware information?

Tags: javascript, php, system, hardware

I am working on a "system requirements" project - where I need to know my visitors system hardware. It must work online. I know I can get the visitors GPU info but can't get CPU, RAM, HDD, etc.

Is it possible to obtain a visitor's hardware information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464896/get-cpu-gpu-memory-information

Comment: Well but i cant see info for cpu/ram/hdd?

Comment: You cannot and you should not. It's an invasion of privacy. If you want info about your customer's system, ask them.

Comment: Why, how to use this information for bad things? thanks for reply :)

Comment: Formatting, grammar added clarity to the actual question - apologies if I missed the gist.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

PHP runs on the server and only has access to it and data sent to it.

Javascript runs on the client but is sandboxed and has no direct access to the hardware layer (just limited information about the GPU).

All services that do offer this kind of "scanning" (nVidia, etc) - use a downloadable application that scans the hardware for that platform then returns the result to the web service.

So you can do it, but you would need some additional software that can run on the client machine that can access the data you require.