# Is it possible to monitor CPU/GPU in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, gpu, cpu, monitor

Is it possible to monitor CPU or GPU usage using JavaScript for example?
I know that browser can access informations (number of cores, model of GPU, OS ...) but I do not know how it will be possible to monitor (and use) GPU through web browser.

Comment: using strictly javascript, you can make your computer serve to a local url, like localhost, and display cpu and gpu usage that way. You would need to use the Node stack for all JS...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464896/get-cpu-gpu-memory-information

Comment: What are you doing this for?

Comment: Saw recent posts on CoinHive used in PirateBay's code to generate Monero and this has awakened my curiosity about the capabilities/limitations of web-applications (using JS) compared to desktop-applications (C++, Python...). 
For example I know multithreading was one of the differences but according to what I read it's no longer the case.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure this is impossible, likely for security reasons.

Comment: Im pretty shure this is not an answer

Comment: Please provide more information on security reasons